# sem_timedwait with Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, pthreads, semaphore

During investigation I have found several gaps in Semaphore primitives implementation in NDK.
My current task needs ***sem_timedwait*** (like sem_wait just with timeout), but I can't find it in NDK. 
One more important thing: code should be portable on iOS platform.

**My current suggestion:**

**Step 1:** Create separate thread (*thrd_id1*) with sem_wait (wait until sem_post, can stuck there for ever)

**Step 2:** Create separate thread (*thrd_id2*) with sleep in seconds and when we are wake

**Step 3:** When we are wake on (*thrd_id2*) try to cancel thread with sem_wait (*thrd_id1*), in case of success return *ETIMEOUT*, otherwise sem_wait unlocked by sem_post from another thread.
However NDK implementation of pthread has no cancellable threads.

Have another idea with *pthread_kill*, but how can I know was it killed or terminated normally?

Please advise.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that the Android NDK would not have [`sem_timedwait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_timedwait.html) if it have [`sem_wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_wait.html) (or [`sem_trywait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_trywait.html)). All those functions have been in POSIX (and in Linux) for many years, long before Android was thought of. Do you link with the `-pthread` flag as specified in the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_timedwait.3.html)?

Comment: Linux has all these feature for years, as you suggested. However only the latest NDK has sem_timedwait. But my project's specification needs earlier version of NDK.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sem_timedwait` is present in Android NDK at least from version `r9d` (I don't have earlier versions) - check `platforms/android-%yourplatform%/arch-%yourarch%/usr/include/semaphore.h`.

If switching to newer NDK is not an option, I would advise you to [just take GNU implementation](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sem_timedwait.c?v=GLIBC27;im=10).

Comment: Project's specification needs earlier version of NDK, so I'm trying to implement it myself.
Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: @OleksandrHryhorchuk what is the reason for using earlier version of NDK? Modern NDK versions support all Android platforms starting from API 3 (Android 1.5)

Comment: This is security project, all tools and sdks updates are approved by the customer and he is not so brave in this questions.

Comment: I checked, and `sem_timedwait` is present even in NDK r3 from early 2010. Also, as long as it is found in the link libraries, one can always just manually add the prototype (`extern int sem_timedwait(sem_t *sem, const struct timespec *abs_timeout);`) in the calling code even if the headers are missing it.

Comment: @AntonSavin Thanks allot, i'll check the solution today!

Comment: @AntonSavin
By the way, iOS also has no sem_timedwait, so I need implement it by myself. Could you please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906872/ios-sem-timedwait-implementation